# A HREF Modify the value causes the nested element inside A tag to be deleted

Tags: jquery

The following A HREF element modified through the jquery deletes the nested IMG element .

```
<table id="newHead" width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="display: none;border: 1px #000066 groove;">
    <tr height="25px"> 
        <td style="text-align: center;padding-left: 10px;"><strong style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px; ">
        <font color="#000066"> Report</font></strong></td>
        <td> <a id="url" href="mmRep.do?action=getXLSummReport&reportId="><img align="right" hspace="850px" src="images/graph_bar/graph_Excel.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="0"> </a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This  jquery removes the nested IMG element(

)

```
var newurl = $("a#url").attr("href") + reportId;
$("a#url").attr("href",newurl);
```

After i modify the href attr value, the html becomes likes this, the img element vanishes

```
<td> 
<a id="url" href="mmRep.do?action=getXLSummReport&reportId=75">
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue.  What else is happening in the code that replaces the URL?

Comment: Could not reproduce this behavior, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hfj4g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nope, it doesn't.](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/wZthm/)

Make sure your `reportId` contains an integer, and nothing else, like  quote `"` or a single quote `'`.